# Getting h1 tag value using php

Tags: php

I want to submit the value under h1 tag into my Sql table

Example, if this where the given input string:

```
 <h1>hello</h1>
```

how to echo "hello" with php (this is a hidden value to submit along with form)

```
 <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php
    echo $Pattern = "/<h1>(.*?)<\/h1>/";
    ?>" />
```

the above one writes

```
/<h1>(.*?)</h1>/
```

into my table

Comment: if it is a hidden value, then why do you need to have <h1> </h1> tags around it?

Comment: can you use javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Eritrea He actually needs the innerHTML from h1

Comment: you can't get h1 value directly into input?

Comment: I still don't understand his question

Comment: yea me too, if you printing or have access to the h1.. just simply put this value into hidden input... where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you escaping the HTML before attempting to insert it into the database try `mysql_real_escape_string($htmlyouwant);`

and

```
echo  "<h1>".$message."</h1>";
```